# Recursive sorting in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, recursion

I have a hash that contains keys that correspond to database subscripts, but the database can have multidimensional records so the key could be a single subscript, or a list of subscripts.

I need to find a way to sort these records so I can print them in a logical order.

Example:

```
my $data = {
    '1,1,1' => 'data1',
    '1,2'   => 'data2',
    '1,1,3' => 'stuff',
    '2,1,1' => 'data3',
    '2,1,2' => 'data4',
    '2,1,3' => 'data blah',
    '2,2,2' => 'datawk2n',
    '3,1,2' => 'more',
};

# Should print the keys in the properly sorted order
print join "\n", sort some_function keys %$data;

sub some_function {
    # Do some sorting magikz
}
```

I want it to sort by the leftmost subscript first.  If the leftmost value is identical I want to move to the next value and compare those.  If those are identical I want to continue to the next one ... and so on ... until all possibilities are exhausted.

This will most likely involve some recursion, but I can't figure out how to make recursion work with those fancy `$a` and `$b` variables.

What can I put in `some_function` to get the following output?

```
1,1,1
1,1,3
1,2
2,1,1
2,1,2
2,1,3
2,2,2
3,1,2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following is the fastest solution (by far!):

```
my @sorted_keys =
   map { join ',', unpack 'N*', $_ }
   sort
   map { pack 'N*', split /,/, $_ }
   keys(%$data);
```

If you want something simpler, and still quite fast, you could use a "natural sort".

- [Sort::Key::Natural](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort::Key::Natural)

  ```
  use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort );

  my @sorted_keys = natsort(keys(%$data));
  ```
- [Sort::Naturally](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort::Naturally)

  ```
  use Sort::Naturally qw( nsort );

  my @sorted_keys = nsort(keys(%$data));
  ```

---

Benchmarks:

```
       Rate   SN  SKN  grt
SN   3769/s   -- -40% -88%
SKN  6300/s  67%   -- -79%
grt 30362/s 705% 382%   --
```

Benchmark code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark          qw( cmpthese );
use List::Util         qw( shuffle );
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( );
use Sort::Naturally    qw( );

my @keys =
   shuffle
      split ' ',
         '1 1,0 1,1 1,1,1 1,1,3 1,2 2,1,1 2,1,2 2,1,3 2,2,2 3,1,2 10,1,1';

sub grt {
   my @sorted_keys =
      map { join ',', unpack 'N*', $_ }
      sort
      map { pack 'N*', split /,/, $_ }
      @keys;
}

sub SKN { my @sorted_keys = Sort::Key::Natural::natsort(@keys); }

sub SN { my @sorted_keys = Sort::Naturally::nsort(@keys); }

cmpthese(-3, {
   grt => \&grt,
   SKN => \&SKN,
   SN  => \&SN,
});
```

Comment: Isn't `keys(@keys)` just grabbing the indices of the array `@keys`, and therefore packing the integers 0..11 and sorting based entirely on array index?

Comment: Indeed viewing the contents of `@sorted_keys` seems to reveal it contains a list of 0..11 in ascending order.  Removing `keys()` has the desired effect. And though this may have some impact on the benchmark, I suspect it would still win.

Comment: Under the `keys(@keys)` code I got 41818/s for grt. Under just `@keys` I got 30168/s. So while it does impact performance considerably, it's still a fantastic approach, leaving the other methods in the dust.

Comment: Your first snippet is the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). Nice to see it in action :-)

Comment: This is brilliant.  I'm glad I posted this question.  I did eventually find my own solution but it's total garbage compared to this one!

Comment: Could this also be made faster if you split on `','` instead of using a regex?

Comment: @tjwrona1992: The first argument to `split` is always interpreted as a pattern.

Comment: @tjwrona1992, If anything, that would be slower, since it would have to compile the regex pattern at run-time, whereas `split /,/` compiles the pattern at compile-time.

Comment: @Perl Dog, It's actually a specific case of ST called [Guttman Rosler Transform](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=145659). GRT is a ST where `sort`'s default compare function is used.

Comment: GRT is faster than other ST because the comparing is all done in the sort function, avoid relatively slow calls to Perl subs. /// I've tried a few GRT variants that didn't require reconstructing the string, but they weren't any faster.

Comment: I haven't heard of the term "GRT" before (only of ST) and was already wondering about your function's name. Thank you for the link. Your code is a perfect example for a GRT. :-)

Answer (score 4):

<strike>I thought the [`Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally) module would help you here, but it seems not</strike>

I must have had a bug in my test. This works fine

```
use Sort::Naturally 'nsort';
say for nsort keys %$data;
```

I recommend either this or the `Sort::Key::Naturally` solution as they are the clearest

It is bad practice to chase speed of execution, especially at the expense of readability, before there is evidence that a given solution is too slow. Even then it is foolish to randomly optimise chunks of your code in the hope of making a difference, and your solution should be run through a profiler to discover where it would be most fruitful to make enhancements

---

There is no need for recursion. This program shows a sort subroutine `by_elements` which simply compares each item in the list until it finds either a mismatch or the end of one of the lists

In the former case the result is just the comparison of the two differ elements, and in the latter it is a comparison of the *number of elements* in the two lists

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $data = {
    '1,1,1'  => 'data1',
    '1,2'    => 'data2',
    '1,1,3'  => 'stuff',
    '2,1,1'  => 'data3',
    '2,1,2'  => 'data4',
    '2,1,3'  => 'data blah',
    '2,2,2'  => 'datawk2n',
    '3,1,2'  => 'more',
    '10,1,1' => 'odd',
    '1,1'    => 'simple',
    '1,0'    => 'simple0',
    '1'      => 'simpler',
};

say for sort by_elements keys %$data;

sub by_elements {
    my ( $aa, $bb ) = map [/\d+/g], $a, $b;
    for ( my $i = 0; $i < @$aa and $i < @$bb; ++$i ) {
        my $cmp = $aa->[$i] <=> $bb->[$i];
        return $cmp if $cmp;
    }
    return @$aa <=> @$bb;
}
```

#### output

```
1
1,0
1,1
1,1,1
1,1,3
1,2
2,1,1
2,1,2
2,1,3
2,2,2
3,1,2
10,1,1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `natsort` of [`Sort::Key::Natural`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use Sort::Key::Natural qw(natsort);

my %data = (
    '1,1,1'  => 'data1',
    '1,2'    => 'data2',
    '1,1,3'  => 'stuff',
    '2,1,1'  => 'data3',
    '2,1,2'  => 'data4',
    '2,1,3'  => 'data blah',
    '2,2,2'  => 'datawk2n',
    '10,1,2' => 'more',
);

say for natsort keys %data;
```

Outputs:

```
1,1,1
1,1,3
1,2
2,1,1
2,1,2
2,1,3
2,2,2
10,1,2
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for recursion, just a loop that you can break out of.

```
sub some_function {
    my @aa = split /,/, $a;
    my @bb = split /,/, $b;
    my $cmp = 0;
    for (my $i=0; $i<@aa || $i<@bb; $i++) {
        $cmp = $aa[$i] <=> $bb[$i];
        last if $cmp;
    }
    $cmp;
}
```

---

But if your heart is set on a recursive solution, there's

```
sub aref_sort_recurse {
    my ($c,$d) = @_;
    @$c ? @$d ? shift @$c <=> shift @$d || aref_sort_recurse($c,$d) ? 1 : -@$d
}

sub some_function {
    aref_sort_recurse( [split /,/, $a], [split /,/, $b] )
}
```

Comment: `Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>)` at the line `$cmp = $aa[$i] <=> $bb[$i]` You are comparing elements off the end of one of the lists

Comment: Not with the test data, but you need to go past the end of a list to distinguish between `"4,5"` and `"4,5,6"`

Comment: Yes. I think your were (un)lucky that there was only one key `1,2` with two values and none other beginning with `1,2` or `1,3` or more

Comment: That is, "Use of uninitialized value ..." is a feature.

Comment: Yes. I knew that. It makes your code superior in ways that many may not recognise. I salute you

Comment: Now you've made me wonder about a recursive solution that uses `local` to alter `$a` and `$b` in nested calls. No, that's horrible, but much more baroque than the cheaty way of declaring your sort subroutine with a `($$)` prototype

Comment: Yeah, but you'd have to check if `$a` and `$b` are references each time and it gets ugly fast.

Comment: Time for a tied string!